# IE11 crashing when loading large amounts of data into a HTML table

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

When I try to load data to table, that has a lot of rows (about 100K), The IE crashes and I receieved this error:

> Faulting application name: IEXPLORE.EXE, version: 11.0.9600.17840,
>   time stamp: 0x555fe1bb Faulting module name: MSHTML.dll, version:
>   11.0.9600.17842, time stamp: 0x5565cf99 Exception code: 0xc0000602 Fault offset: 0x0088930d Faulting process id: 0xc68 Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01d14b89505a40f8 Faulting application path:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE Faulting module
>   path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSHTML.dll Report Id:
>   326e9329-b77d-11e5-80bd-0050568d51ac Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

I tried to run this in Chrome, and even it is not so fast, it works there!

Someone has any idea?

```
    <tbody >
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                      //  the flag for sum row is: the date/תאריך column in empty = ""    
                    if (Model.Rows[i].ItemArray[ViewBag.FlagIndex].ToString() != "")
                        {
                             <tr>
                                @for (int j = 0; j < Model.Columns.Count; j++)
                                {
                                    //width="8%"
                                   <td 
                                       style="border: #cdcdcd 1px solid;
                                       border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
                                       text-align: center;">

                                       @Html.Label(Model.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString())
                                   </td>                           
                                }
                             </tr>
                        }
                    else
                        {   
                                //don't sort sum row
                             <tbody >
                                 <tr>
                                      @for (int k = 0; k < Model.Columns.Count; k++)
                                      {   
                                          <td
                                              style="border: #cdcdcd 1px solid;
                                              border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
                                              color: #3d3d3d;
                                              background-color: #96bfc7;
                                              text-align: center;">
                                              @Html.Label(Model.Rows[i].ItemArray[k].ToString())
                                              </td>     
                                      }
                                 </tr>
                             </tbody>
                        }
                }
    </tbody>
```

Comment: What kind of data table? .Net or the Javascript one? or do you mean just a HTML table?

Comment: I edit my queastion, and add a code.. I transfer a model of datatable, and build the table inside the view

Comment: As an FYI, a [datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables) can mean several [different things](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable). Your just creating a HTML table using Razor. Please remember to add the relevant tags regarding the technology stack your using to save confusion.

Comment: Sorry, but I didnt understand, how can I fix this problem that IE crashes?